# Polymorphism: Instance class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Is it necessary to instance the class another class has been derived from?
If I dont, I can access its methods anyway, like in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
struct Class1 {
public:
    void func();
};

struct Class2 : public Class1 {
    // Class1 c1; <-- is this necessary?
};

void Class1::func(){
    std::cout << "function called" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    Class2 c2;
    c2.func();
}
```

I get the expected `function called`.
But in some examples I see that the base class is being instanced in the derived class: `Class1 c1;`. What is it for?

Comment: Every instance of `Class2` is also an instance of `Class1`. This is pretty much what "inheritance" means.

Comment: Can you post such an example? I've never seen anything like that. Having a member of the same type as a base is bizarre.

Comment: Inheritance is a type of "is a.." relation. "Class2 is a Class1". It therefore has also a complete instance of Class1 included. A member of base-type only makes sense to build a syntatic relation of "is a..." together with "has a...". I can't think of any examples that make sense... Perhaps... a `class DualEngine: public Engine { Engine e2; }` class which is a Engine and has another Engine so there need to be 2 Engines in total... But this one is quite artificial.

Comment: In fact I just stumbled across a case where this makes sense: I have a Matrix class here which is used as base and a class which does jacobi diagonalization as child. The jacobi class operates on the "base" data but stores the eigenvectors in another explicit instance of base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to instance the class another class has been derived from?

No, it is absolutely not necessary.

> But in some examples I see that the base class is being instanced in the derived class: `Class1 c1;`. What is it for?

Without knowing what those examples concretely deal with - i.e. what was the semantics of those classes - it's not easy to explain them in a meaningful way. However, when you create a data member of a certain type, your object has a sub-object of that type. So when you do:

```
struct Y { };

struct X
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    Y c;
};
```

Every object of type `X` will have a subobject `a` of type `int`, a subobject `b` of type `b`, and a subobject `c` of type `Y`. You would be accessing that with the dot notation, as done below:

```
Y foo();

X x;
std::cout << x.a;
x.b = "Hello, World!";
X.c = foo();
```

Similarly, when a class `D` derives from a base class `B`, it contains a sub-object of type `B`, and implicitly inherits all the data members of `B`:

```
struct B
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

struct D : B
{
    bool c;
};

// ...

D d;
d.c = true;
d.b = "Hello, Base Class!";
d.a = 42;
```

Now in your case, the class `Class2` apart from deriving from `Class1` also has a data member of type `Class1`. Notice, that this data member is *not* the base sub-object of `Class2`, but an *additional* member sub-object. So what does this mean?

Take this with a grain of salt, but in order to develop intuition, you can think that inheritance models the "IS-A" relationship, while data membership models the "HAS-A" relationship.

So the fact that `Class2` derives publicly from `Class1` models the fact that "All `Class2` objects are `Class1` objects", and therefore inherit all of `Class1`'s data members. This explains why objects of type `Class2` have a base sub-object of type `Class1`.

On the other hand, the fact that `Class2` has a data member of type `Class1` models the fact that "All `Class2` objects contain/embed/own an object of type `Class1`". This explains why objects of type `Class2` have a member sub-object of type `Class1`.

Now in the particular case of the examples you mention both of the above semantics are modeled at the same time - i.e. a `Class2` both IS-A and HAS-A `Class1` - but that is by no means necessary. Not every `thingy` which IS-A `widget` also HAS-A `widget`.

I hope this makes sense to you in an abstract way. Whether the design is correct or not mostly depends on the semantics of your `Class1` and `Class2` objects, and on what they are meant to model, but the message is:

> **If `Class2` derives from `Class1`, there is nothing that forces you to add a `Class1` data member to `Class2`**.

Comment: (+1) For the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have a base class member variable in the derived class in this case. Also polymorphism applies only for pointer and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary.

```
class Base {

}

class Derived : public Base {

}
```

The `Derived` class will inherit the members of the `Base` class.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely isn't necessary. Without seeing the examples you are referring to it's hard to tell why the author would have created the instance. Most likely it is to show what happens when Class2::func() calls c1.func().